# TYPO3 frontend login stopped working after update

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

I just updated my TYPO3 v.7 install to 7.6.29 and now frontend logins stopped working. `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS[FE][loginSecurity]` is set to 'rsa', rsaauth and saltedpasswords are enabled. I do not use a custom template for the login form and I checked that `data-rsa-encryption=""` is present on the password field. 
Still, when I attempt to log in, I just get log entries stating that there was a login attempt without password.

Everything worked fine before the update. On updating, I flushed all caches, including opcode, and ran all Update Wizards and the Database Analyzer.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Okay, after a bit of digging, I found where the problem is possibly located: The password is not hashed before the form is submitted. The form code only contains an empty `onsubmit="; return true;"` where a hashing function probably should be called. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, re-clearing all caches, clearing opcode cache and deleting all of typo3temp/ fixed this problem.